# I can't use my static JS files in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I'm new to NodeJS. I'm calling my static javascript file from within my ejs file. It is not outputting anything onto the console.

My .ejs file:

```
<head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/calc.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>...</body>
```

My static js (calc.js) file:

```
console.log("WHY IS THIS NOT WORKING?!");//this is it I have NO MORE CODE HERE
```

I have added **app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));** in my app.js.

My static JS file is in public --> javascripts --> calc.js

thanks.

Comment: can you define your directory structure and the the js file code where u use this console

Comment: Sorry, just added it. @AkhileshSingh. This is all the code in my JS file I have nothing else as of now.

Comment: okk Let me check Your Code Seems ok

Comment: Your Css File Is Coming

Comment: @AkhileshSingh Yeah, the CSS file is working fine.

Comment: I check each and Everything your Code looks Correct There is problem in your directory structure ? Check the name of the javascripts Folder where you place calc.js and also check it is at the same level of stylesheet. If everything Is correct then say me where you check the console. and the which Browser.?

Comment: I check the console in the run window. I'm running this on chrome.

Comment: can you take a screen-shot of your complete directory structure and post in your question For reference and also check in your calc.js your are using script tag then remove the script tag from calc.js.

Comment: Can you load the static file directly in the browser? i.e. localhost:javascripts/calc.js. It won't run but you can double check that it is reachable.

Comment: @HeadCode yeah if I go to http://localhost:3000/javascripts/calc.js it works.  this is a screen shot of my project http://imgur.com/SeH1wQE

Comment: I see you have an index.js and an index.ejs. Are you sure you are routing to the correct one?

Comment: Yeah, the variables title etc are all working.

Comment: Really puzzling. The very last thing I can think of is clearing the browser cache or restarting the browser. And WebStorm for good measure. :-) And with that I have to leave for the evening.

Comment: Can you inspect the network tab in the develop tool in chrome? just to make sure the request to /javascripts/calc.js is successful?

Answer (score 0):

In app.use() you are joining __dirname and the folder "public", yet in your ejs file the src to your script is at the root, not under "public." This might be the issue.

Comment: If I make it public/javascripts/calc.js it still doesn't work.

Comment: In express the static paths are relative to the folder named in the "use" statement. In other words, do not use "public" in the path.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use('/public',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your app.js.
`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))`
It's working for me.